# Can I add a juju relation when the agent-state of the unit is still pending?

Tags: juju

Can I add a relation between two units when the units are still in "pending" state? Does the "add relation" wait for the units to become "started"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Juju will queue up the connections until the units are ready.